# How to properly parse and strip my output in Python to then assign Key Value pairs

Tags: python, algorithm, netmiko

I'm currently trying to write a script so that I can display network information on a graph. Unfortunately, I'm not having too much success in what I need to get done. Here is the output I have to work with:

Temperature Sensors:
Unit     Sensor  Description       Temp (C)    State           Max_Temp (C)

---

1        1       PHY               32          Normal          40
1        2       REAR              38          Normal          45
1        3       CPU               40          Normal          48

Temperature Status: Normal

Fan Duty Level: 46%

Fans:
Unit Fan Description    Type      Speed         Duty level    State

---

1    1   FAN-1          Fixed     6617          46%           Operational
1    2   FAN-2          Fixed     6482          46%           Operational

With that being said, I'm only concerned about the Fan speed (not percentage) and the 3 fields (PHY, CPU, and REAR) with their corresponding Temp values (not the max value, just the current value). What I would like my output to look like is the following:

{'PHY': '32', 'REAR': '38', 'CPU': '40', 'FAN-1': 6617, 'FAN-2': 6482}

The reason behind the key value pairs is that I utilize a tool called Logicmonitor that can take external scripting from network equipment and draw the values on a graph that we can track historically.

The closest I've gotten my output to is the following:

['\n', '1', '1', 'P', 'H', 'Y', '3', '2', 'N', 'o', 'r', 'm', 'a', 'l', '4', '0', '\n', '1', '2', 'R', 'E', 'A', 'R', '3', '8', 'N', 'o', 'r', 'm', 'a', 'l', '4', '5', '\n', '1', '3', 'C', 'P', 'U', '4', '0', 'N', 'o', 'r', 'm', 'a', 'l', '4', '8', '\n', '\n', 'T', 'e', 'm', 'p', 'e', 'r', 'a', 't', 'u', 'r', 'e', 'S', 't', 'a', 't', 'u', 's', ':', 'N', 'o', 'r', 'm', 'a', 'l', '\n', '\n', 'F', 'a', 'n', 'D', 'u', 't', 'y', 'L', 'e', 'v', 'e', 'l', ':', '4', '6', '%', '\n', '\n', 'F', 'a', 'n', 's', ':', '\n', 'U', 'n', 'i', 't', 'F', 'a', 'n', 'D', 'e', 's', 'c', 'r', 'i', 'p', 't', 'i', 'o', 'n', 'T', 'y', 'p', 'e', 'S', 'p', 'e', 'e', 'd', 'D', 'u', 't', 'y', 'l', 'e', 'v', 'e', 'l', 'S', 't', 'a', 't', 'e', '\n', '1', '1', 'F', 'A', 'N', '-', '1', 'F', 'i', 'x', 'e', 'd', '6', '6', '5', '0', '4', '6', '%', 'O', 'p', 'e', 'r', 'a', 't', 'i', 'o', 'n', 'a', 'l', '\n', '1', '2', 'F', 'A', 'N', '-', '2', 'F', 'i', 'x', 'e', 'd', '6', '4', '7', '4', '4', '6', '%', 'O', 'p', 'e', 'r', 'a', 't', 'i', 'o', 'n', 'a', 'l', '\n', '\n']

At this point, I know I'm in the right general direction, but I'm unable to figure out where my end destination needs to be. Here is my current script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import netmiko

connection =netmiko.ConnectHandler(ip="1.2.3.4", port="22", device_type="ubiquiti_edgeswitch", username="admin", password="password", secret="password")

#defining a list to be used
output = {}

#assigning the list to the output
output = connection.send_command("show environment | exclude -- begin PHY")

#stripping all leading and trailing spaces from a list of strings
output_new = [item.replace(' ','') for item in output]

#removing any unnecessary spaces from list
while('' in output_new):
    output_new.remove('')

print(output_new)

connection.disconnect()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the assumption that the "arguments" remain their position in relation to each key (e.g. the value for `PHY` always comes directly after the keyword `PHY`), you could use a dictionary that maps each key to what the index offset of the value from the keyword is in the output, and then construct your dictionary from that.

So, for example, in the case of the string
`1 1 PHY 32 Normal 40 1 2 REAR 38 Normal 45 1 3 CPU 40 Normal 48`, the "value" of the keyword `PHY` has an offset of 1. This means that if we split the string by spaces, we know that the value of `PHY` will be found at the index of `PHY` + 1.

This idea is implemented in the following code-snippet:

```py
offsets = {
    "PHY": 1,
    "REAR": 1,
    "CPU": 1,
    "FAN-1": 2,
    "FAN-2": 2,
}

data = {}

words = output.split()

for key in offsets:
    index = words.index(key) + offsets[key]
    data[key] = words[index]
```

Adding this logic to your existing code, we would get:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import netmiko

connection =netmiko.ConnectHandler(ip="1.2.3.4", port="22", device_type="ubiquiti_edgeswitch", username="admin", password="password", secret="password")

#defining a list to be used
output = {}

#assigning the list to the output
output = connection.send_command("show environment | exclude -- begin PHY")
words = output.split()

# Defining the offsets of the "values" for each keyword
offsets = {
    "PHY": 1,
    "REAR": 1,
    "CPU": 1,
    "FAN-1": 2,
    "FAN-2": 2,
}

# The processed data
data = {}

# Loop over each keyword and extract its value
for key in offsets:
    index = words.index(key) + offsets[key]
    data[key] = words[index]


print(data)

connection.disconnect()
```

Comment: you have saved me! This will work exactly for what I need. I'm an IT guy by trade and a lousy programmer with a few classes I've probably forgot under my belt. Thank you so much for the solid explanation and how you went about solving the problem. I was trying to attack it from a different angle and use some poor code logic doing so. You rock!

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to your question, but the recommended way to solve the problem:

There are parsers that can read structured data from network show commands. Netmiko currently supports textFSM, ttp and genie. You can see how to use them in netmiko in the examples section: [netmiko examples](https://github.com/ktbyers/netmiko/blob/develop/EXAMPLES.md)

Comment: Thanks for giving this example! I tried to utilize it myself, but it was going to take some work and tinkering to get it to work. I will definitely be utilizing this for the future. Have a good day!